# Effect of temperature on the electrical conductivity of kerosene

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

In the short article (1927) by Morehouse, C. A. [ref 1], he references Jones [ref 2] saying that: "It was found that the resistance of the oil decreases steadily with a rise in temperature until the temperature reached 75°C. The resistance then seemed to remain fairly constant until the temperature rose further to 90°C. At this temperature the resistance seemed to break down suddenly."

I have not been able to find any theoretical or experimental data that supports that claim although I have found this to happen in the "wild" (aka "don't try this at home" kind of thing).  Is there any reasonable explanation as to why the resistance would drop?  I am particularly interested in seeing what the resistance is between kerosene's flashpoint (~38°C) to somewhere under the autoignition temperature (~210°C), but would be happy to see any curve from (38°C-100°C+), assuming the above citation is accurate (I would like to see how much the resistivity breaks down above 90°C).

References:

1. "The Electric Conductivity of Kerosene and Gasoline as a Function of the Temperature" Morehouse, C. A., Proceedings of the Iowa Academy of Science, 34(1),271-272
2. "The influence of the surrounding medium on frictional electricity", J. Herbert Jones, Philosophical Magazine Series 6, November 1925, Volume 50(Issue 299), pp.1160-1177

Answer (score 0):

Your citations are VERY old.  Modern formulations of kerosene and gasoline involve specifications and specification limits that did not exist in 1927.  You need to send a representative sample to the lab.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Yes the citations are old, and the authors are even older.   Sending to the lab is not practical, nor is it probably financially feasible.  If I could find *any* recent (or even old) specifications/limits then there would be no need to send to a lab.  The basic premise as to why the electrical conductance of many fluids increases with an increase in temperature is that as the temperature of the fluid increases, some of the ions become mobile, allowing a current to flow in the presence of an electric field.   (However, that's not true for all fluids.)